# Automatically open up properties when creating a file from template

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

So my work currently migrating from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint Online, one of the blockers we have is that one of our document library (I'm doubting it's a document library and might be a list) have a extensive Metadata.

Anyways they demanded that to have a similar workflow so that when they create a new file from template then it will open up a form to edit the metadata.

I know that the form in properties is customizable with the new experience enabled which is perfect but I have 1 big and 1 small problem.

The small problem is that it opens up the template to a new browser which is fair since you expect the user to edit it since they created it but I wanted to suppress but moer of a preference thing.

The bigger problem is that I can't find a way to automatically open up properties when I create a new file.

My current game plan right now is creating a web part javascript that detects if they created a new file if it does then locate the properties for it but my problem with that is I can't find a way to create a web part for document library and how would I open up properties from web part